# Rearrange sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    bsv_targetgroupattribute1,
    pos.bsv_address_multiline, 
    pos.bsv_memberlist_memberlistcode, 
    pos.owneridname, 
    mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistcode, 
    pos.bsv_count_german, 
    pos.bsv_count_french,
    pos.bsv_count_italian,
    pos.bsv_count_rr,
    pos.bsv_count_english
FROM Filteredbsv_memberlist as mbl_bsv_memberlist
LEFT JOIN Filteredbsv_memberrelation as pos ON pos.bsv_memberlist = mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistid
LEFT JOIN FilteredAccount as CRMAF_FilteredAccount ON CRMAF_FilteredAccount.accountid = pos.bsv_organization
```

I need to rearrange the query to have another entity starting with the From clause. This means that the joins will need to be rearranged to another join.

My new query should then look like this having the joins being rearranged.

```
SELECT 
    pos.bsv_organization,
    CRMAF_org.accountid,
    CRMAF_org.bsv_targetgroupattribute1, 
    pos.bsv_address_multiline, 
    pos.bsv_memberlist_memberlistcode, 
    pos.owneridname, 
    CRMAF_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistcode, 
    pos.bsv_count_german, 
    pos.bsv_count_french,
    pos.bsv_count_italian,
    pos.bsv_count_rr,
    pos.bsv_count_english
FROM FilteredAccount as CRMAF_org
....
....
....
```

Could someone be so kind and help me to get the correct query?
Help is very appreciated.

Comment: A left join B eq. B right join A. But why do you "need" to do this?

Comment: You haven't added any new table to the mix - given the names of these tables, are they themselves views? If it's not already optimal, the query optimizer will likely rearrange your join ordering anyway to (usually) be as efficient as possible.

Comment: I need to to this because the table FilteredAccount needs to be placed right after the FROM clause due to technical purposes.

@Stu: The first cmplete query contains already all tables. The difference in the second query is that the table "FilteredAccount" needs to be placed right after the FROM keyword instead beeing part of the last join. The rest of the clause needs to be rearranged accordingly

Comment: What "technical purposes"? As Stu said, the optimizer will chose the best execution order anyway. You should just write the clearest SQL.

Comment: Changing the join order here will almost certainly have no effect on the query as presented, I'd almost guarantee the execution plan of both would be identical. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    bsv_targetgroupattribute1,
    pos.bsv_address_multiline, 
    pos.bsv_memberlist_memberlistcode, 
    pos.owneridname, 
    mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistcode, 
    pos.bsv_count_german, 
    pos.bsv_count_french,
    pos.bsv_count_italian,
    pos.bsv_count_rr,
    pos.bsv_count_english
FROM FilteredAccount as CRMAF_FilteredAccount    
LEFT JOIN Filteredbsv_memberrelation as pos ON pos.bsv_memberlist = mbl_bsv_memberlist.bsv_memberlistid 
RIGHT JOIN Filteredbsv_memberlist as mbl_bsv_memberlist ON CRMAF_FilteredAccount.accountid = pos.bsv_organization
```

Comment: Thank you for you help :) The issue now is that I get:

The multi-part identifier "pos.bsv_organization" could not be bound.

This because the "pos" alias is declared after the corresponding join.